# R mix function from DepmixS4 package provide different results with exactly same codes

Tags: r, finite-mixture-model, latent-class

I am testing the mix model from the Depmix4 package using simulating data. In the model, I provide the starting values to all parameters to be estimated. However, when I run the same code twice, I get different results, which sometimes are quite different.

My understanding of the model is that it uses the EM estimation. Since I provide the starting values, it should always land on the same result ( even if it land on the local optimization spot twice). Am I wrong?

I attach my simulation model below:

```
M1_ss<- mix(list(X1_1~1,X1_2~1,X1_add1~1,X1_add2~1,X1_3~1,X2~1,X3~1,X4~1,X5~1),
 family = list(multinomial("identity"),
               multinomial("identity"),
               multinomial("identity"),
               multinomial("identity"),
               multinomial("identity"),
 gaussian(), 
 gaussian(),
 gaussian(), 
 gaussian()), 
 data = data_ss,
 nstates = 4, #This is the number of classes
 instart=c(multinomial()$linkinv(c(0,.1,3,5),base=1), 0, .5, 2, 5),
respstart=respstart_1,# I save all variables into a vecor
 prior=~data_ss$c1,
 initdata = data_ss
)
```

here is my data creating procedure:

```
#Genarating 400 random numbers with zero mean-->c1 is the concomitant
c1 = rnorm(I,0,1)
#Assigning the values of beta1 and beta2-->the covariants
Beta10 = 0.1
Beta20 = 3
Beta30 = 5

Beta11 = 0.5
Beta21 = 2
Beta31 = 5

Denominator= 1+exp(Beta11*c1+Beta10)+exp(Beta21*c1+Beta20)+exp(Beta31*c1+Beta30)
#Calculating the matrix of probabilities for three states
vProb2 = cbind(1/Denominator, exp(Beta11*c1+Beta10)/Denominator, exp(Beta21*c1+Beta20)/Denominator ,exp(Beta31*c1+Beta30)/Denominator)
mChoices = t(apply(vProb2, 1, rmultinom, n = 1, size = 1))
dfM = cbind.data.frame(State = apply(mChoices, 1, function(x) which(x==1)), c1)

getMC=function(I){
p1_1=c(0.15,0.4,0.65,0.9)#parameters for bernulli distribution x1_1   
p1_2=c(0.1,0.3,0.6,0.8) #parameters for bernoulli distribution x1_2
p1_3 = matrix(c(0.04,0.7,0.26,0.24,0.46,0.3,0.33,0.33,0.34,0.25,0.24,0.51),byrow = T, nrow = 4,ncol = 3) #parameters for multinomial distribution x1_3
Q = matrix(c(-2,0.2,0,0.3,1,0.5,2,0.2),byrow = T, nrow = 4,ncol = 2) # parameters for normal distribution x2   
M = matrix(c(0,0.5,0.1,0.3,2,0.1,2.5,0.2),byrow = T, nrow = 4,ncol = 2)# parameters for normal distribution x3

X1_1 = matrix(NA, nrow = I, ncol = 1)
X1_2 = matrix(NA, nrow = I, ncol = 1)
X1_3= matrix(NA, nrow = I, ncol = 1)
X1_3_1=matrix(NA, nrow = I, ncol = 3)#middle step for creating the multinomial var
X2 = matrix(NA, nrow = I, ncol = 1)
X3 = matrix(NA, nrow = I, ncol = 1)
S=dfM$State # the state was created when creating concomitant var
c1=dfM$c1 #concomitant var
#prepare the dataset
for (i in 1:I){
      X1_1[i]=ifelse(purrr::rbernoulli(1,p=p1_1[S[i]])=='TRUE',1,0)# binomial var
      X1_2[i]=ifelse(purrr::rbernoulli(1,p=p1_2[S[i]])=='TRUE',1,0)
      X1_3_1[i,] = t(rmultinom(1,1,p1_3[S[i],]))
      X1_3[i]=apply(t(as.data.frame(X1_3_1[i,])),1,function(x)which(x==1)) #create a multinomial variable
      X2[i]=rnorm(1,Q[S[i],1],Q[S[i],2])#+error_1[i]#two continuous var
      X3[i]=rnorm(1,M[S[i],1],M[S[i],2])#+error_2[i]
}
```

Can anyone share with me some knowledge on this? Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

The reason the results can differ from run to run when using the EM in depmixS4 is that we implemented a way to generate random starting values in order to avoid the need for setting starting values for all parameters. This is done by randomly assigning observations to mixture components/hidden states. If you want to avoid this, you can use the `emcontrol` argument in the `mix` (and `depmix`) function to set `random.start = FALSE`.

As the code in the question is not reproducible, I will show this with a reproducible example based on the `mix` help file

```r
library(depmixS4)

# four binary items on the balance scale task
data(balance)

# define a latent class model
instart=c(0.5,0.5)
set.seed(1)
respstart=runif(16)
# note that ntimes argument is used to make this a mixture model
mod <- mix(list(d1~1,d2~1,d3~1,d4~1), data=balance, nstates=2,
           family=list(multinomial(),multinomial(),multinomial(),multinomial()),
           respstart=respstart,instart=instart)

# estimate the model
set.seed(2)
fm1 <- fit(mod)

# estimate the model again; note same result, but in a different number
# of iterations, so EM has not proceeded in exactly the same way
set.seed(6)
fm2 <- fit(mod)

# Do it again, but now set random.start in EM to FALSE
set.seed(2)
fm1 <- fit(mod, emcontrol=em.control(random.start = FALSE))
# and again, now we get exactly the same result
set.seed(6)
fm2 <- fit(mod, emcontrol=em.control(random.start = FALSE))
```

The relevant output is

```r
> # estimate the model
> set.seed(2)
> fm1 <- fit(mod)
converged at iteration 26 with logLik: -1083.036 
> 
> # estimate the model again; note same result, but in a different number
> # of iterations, so EM has not proceeded in exactly the same way
> set.seed(6)
> fm2 <- fit(mod)
converged at iteration 28 with logLik: -1083.036 
> 
> # Do it again, but now set random.start in EM to FALSE
> set.seed(2)
> fm1 <- fit(mod, emcontrol=em.control(random.start = FALSE))
converged at iteration 21 with logLik: -1083.036 
> # and again, now we get exactly the same result
> set.seed(6)
> fm2 <- fit(mod, emcontrol=em.control(random.start = FALSE))
converged at iteration 21 with logLik: -1083.036
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the kind explanation. Apologize for the unclear codes, but in my case, I did not set starting values by random (I did not use runif), I input specific starting values for the parameters (e.g. for starting values of the concomitant, I put instart=c(multinomial()$linkinv(c(0,.1,3,5),base=1), 0, .5, 2, 5) in all trials; similar inputs for respstart). Why would I still get different estimation output every time? Is this also due to the fact that the algorithm assign observation into hidden states randomly?